# Validation org.hibernate.validator.constraints with custom form-login

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, spring-security

I'm using spring security to authenticate the custom form-login. But when I configure my spring-security.xml to use the custom form-login, validation doesn't work

spring-security:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <form-login login-page="/login" username-parameter="email" password-parameter="password" authentication-failure-url="/faillogin" />
</http>
```

Form in login.jsp:

```
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="userLogin" action="/login" autocomplete="off">
    <sf:input path="email" class="input-login" placeholder="Seu Email" /> <br/>
    <sf:password path="password" class="input-login" placeholder="Senha" /> <br/>
    <sf:errors path="*" element="div" cssClass="error" />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" class="btn-padrao btn-left"></input>
</sf:form>
```

Entity:

```
public class UserLogin {

    @NotBlank(message="Email blank")
    @Email(message="{userlogin.email_valid}")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message="Password blank")
    @Size(min=8, max=20, message="{userlogin.pasword_size}")
    private String password;

    public UserLogin() { }

    public UserLogin(String email, String password) { 
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll probably get better answers if you explain what the failure is rather than simply saying it doesn't work. There's likely to be different solutions depending on whether it does nothing, generates an error, or turns the Moon into a giant lime. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).